# Ansible - populate file with dictionary, one section at a time

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible, yaml

I see a lot of examples of iterating through dictionaries with Ansible, but I want to populate an entire section of a file with one item in the loop before continuing onto the next item.

For example, I have a dictionary as follows:

```
fruits:
  apple:
    color: red
    shape: round
    taste: sweet
  blueberry:
    color: blue
    shape: round
    taste: sour
```

Before moving on to 'blueberry', I need apple to fill out a few stanzas in a file. E.g.

```
#############
# apple #
#############

[Stanza1]
Name = apple
Taste = "This is a sweet fruit"

[Stanza2]
Color = red
Shape = "apples are round"

#############
# blueberry #
#############

[Stanza1]
Name = blueberry
Taste = "This is a sour fruit"

[Stanza2]
Color = blue
Shape = "blueberry are round"
```

I was thinking of using the 'ini_file' module for this, but I believe ini_file would iterate through every stanza with my list of fruits before going onto the next stanza - which I don't want, I want one fruit to populate all sections before moving on to the next fruit. Any suggestions on how to set this up would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason for not templating the whole file?

Comment: dont forget to close your question by validating the answer....

Answer (score 1):

1. you create a template file **stanzas.j2** in templates folder:

---

```
{% for fruit in fruits | dict2items %}
#############
# {{fruit.key}} #
#############

[Stanza1]
Name = {{fruit.key}}
Taste = "This is a {{fruit.value.taste}} fruit"

[Stanza2]
Color = {{fruit.value.color}}
Shape = "{{fruit.key}} are {{fruit.value.shape}}"

{% endfor %}
```

---

2. create a playbook using template module:

---

```
- name: "make this working"
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    fruits:
      apple:
        color: red
        shape: round
        taste: sweet
      blueberry:
        color: blue
        shape: round
        taste: sour

  tasks:
    - name: generate stanzas file
      #delegate_to: localhost
      template:
        src: stanzas.j2   #cherche dans templates
        dest: ./files/stanzas.ini
```

---

result stanzas.ini:

```
#############
# apple #
#############

[Stanza1]
Name = apple
Taste = "This is a sweet fruit"

[Stanza2]
Color = red
Shape = "apple are round"

#############
# blueberry #
#############

[Stanza1]
Name = blueberry
Taste = "This is a sour fruit"

[Stanza2]
Color = blue
Shape = "blueberry are round"
```